# sending pytest report to logger

Tags: logging, pytest

I am using pytest for running my automation framework tests and I've created my own logger inside this automation framework.
Now , my question is how can I send to this logger the report message that pytest generates when failing on assertion? 
For example:
I want to send to the logger this message

```
test_basic.py:73 (test_basic)
online != Online

Expected :Online
Actual   :online
 <Click to see difference>
...
...
def test_basic(some_fixture):
    test_obj = TestClass()

>  test_obj.run(some_fixture)  

test_basic.py:78:
```

Comment: It's possible by implementing custom hooks. For example, in [`pytest_assertrepr_compare`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_assertrepr_compare) you can add own behaviour on failed assertions and in [`pytest_exception_interact`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact) on unexpected exceptions raised.

Comment: It is very helpful, Thank You!   
I have only one problem and that my logger is "module" scope fixture , In such case how can I write a hook for it?

Comment: No, you'll need to instantiate the logger earlier than in a fixture (via a global variable e.g. on module level or in an early hook like `pytest_configure`).